# How to find small hotels / cheap rooms in the French Alps in August

Tags: france, bookings, alps

I know about booking.com and just started looking at Gîtes de France® (https://www.gites-de-france.com). What are some good ways to find rooms to rent in August? A friend and I will rent motorcycles in Geneva and ride south through the French Alps, Gorge du Verdun, Route des Grandes Alpes, Chamonix, and return to Geneva. Our trip will be from August 15 through August 26. Since this is the height of the tourist season, I want to make reservations.

Our current plan is to stay in most places one night, but I will try to modify the itinerary to make some places a two-night stay. We are not picky about the accommodations and are looking for hotels, B&Bs, or hostels. We do not need Holiday Inn luxury. Other than the two websites I mentioned, what are good ways to find and reserve rooms?

Comment: You may want to check Airbnb, though I have no idea whether they have decent offers for the area and season. It’s also not necessarily ideal for single-night stays, but YMMV (a lot).

Comment: Although primarily for hikers, the [Cicerone guides](https://www.cicerone.co.uk/walking-in-the-brianconnais) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little labor-intensive but each French *département* (a low-level district or province-like subdivision of the country) will have a tourism website that should be pretty exhaustive. On your itinerary those are:

- [Haute-Savoie](http://www.haute-savoie-tourisme.org/)
- [Savoie](https://www.savoie-mont-blanc.com/en/) (rather confusing website, I think it covers Haute-Savoie too)
- [Isère](https://www.isere-tourisme.com/)
- [Alpes-de-Haute-Provence](https://www.tourisme-alpes-haute-provence.com/)
- [Alpes-Maritimes](https://cotedazurfrance.fr/)

If you know roughly where you may want to stop, you could also look up the tourist office of that specific village or town (without getting too deep in the administrative details nearly all towns would have one, typically for a group of municipalities). Those will also list all types of accommodations.

You can also check AirBnB and Abritel but I suspect that in a holiday area in the high season, most places will have a minimum number of nights to accept a booking.

Comment: I think these pages are just what I was looking for. :-) I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the first posted answer, (local tourist information) I myself often look on one of the big hotel booking sites.

You may not find some of the smaller places but they often have a good spread from hostels and b&b's to good hotels.

One of those sites is booking dot com but there are others as well.

Comment: (+1) Yes me too, definitely agree! But the OP seemed to know about booking.com and it's difficult to find much more without a lot more effort.

Comment: @Relaxed , I missed that in the question. Thanks.